# Minecraft : Mod-making (MCreator) : Redstone Result Event

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

I am currently using a Mod-making Tool called "MCreator" made by Pylo.

I am currently making a Block Element and creating an event when The block is right clicked by a Prismarine Shard, then The block will power redstone.

I did this by doing the following:

- Event : On block rightclicked
- Condition : `itemInPlayersHand[] == Items.prismarine_shard`
- Event parameters (Redstone Power; State of power) : true
- I also checked "Can provide power?" In Advanced properties

The problem is that when I test the mod in a client environment and click the block, it will not power any redstone around it.

I tried to change when the event happens to Print a text and when I tested and clicked on it with a prismarine shard, it printed the text to the console.

So is there something wrong with the Redstone Power event result or am I doing something wrong.

Thanks in Advanced,
Bryan